# What are the keys for a supporting / intersection entity?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

If we have

```
 ____________           /      \             ____________
|   Person   |-------- /        \    ------>|   Location |
|____________|        /  BornIn  \          |_____________
                      \          /
                       \        /
                        \      /

Person(SSN, first name, last name)
BornIn(..)
Location(City, Country, zip-code)
```

where **SSN** is the key for `Person`, and `Location is` determined by all three attributes.

For a weak entity, the key is made up of all attributes of the weak entity + the primary keys (or foreign key) of the owner entity.

1. What is/are the key(s) of `BornIn`?
2. What is/are the key(s) of a weak supporting entity?

I just can't find the answers online yet. This is not homework. I am learning database design....

My bad. It's Many to One relationship.

Answer (score 1):

"Weak entity" simply means it is involved in an identifying relationship (as a child endpoint). And identifying relationship simply means the child entity's key contains the parent's key (so it cannot be identified independently).

`BornIn` is a relationship, not entity so it cannot be "weak" nor it can have a key in the logical model.

In the *physical* model however, `BornIn` *could* be mapped into table and have a key, depending on relationship cardinality:

- Since you say it's many-to-one, it is not mapped to a table so there is no key (and since it is not one-to-one there would be no key on the FK in `Person` table either).
- But if it *were* many-to-many, then `BornIn` would be mapped to a table with a key which is a **compound** of the two parent keys: `{SSN, City, Country, zip-code}`.

Comment: Thanks. Why is `BornIn` not a M-1 relationship? Shouldn't one person maps to at most one birthplace (some may remain unknown)? Thanks.

Comment: @User007 I was simply making a hypothetical point about how a many-to-many relationship would be mapped to physical model. I assumed your question is just one example of many (or many to come, since you are learning) and I wasn't trying to suggest this _particular_ example is many-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

Person Table's PK is ssn
Location table has to have a primary key - location_id (maybe an auto increment value)

the intermediate table - bornIn has ssn and location_id as its columns

therefore you can join the Person table with the Location table via this intermediate table.

```
 SELECT p.first_name,l.city from Person p inner join bornin b on b.ssn = p.ssn 
                                 inner join Location l on l.location_id=b.location_id
```

Comment: Thank you, Sanath. Are you saying that for intermediate table, the attributes are the keys of the other two relations? And they are also the key of the supporting entity? Does this change if it's a weak supporting entity?

Comment: in a weak supporting entity, you think of using all 3 fields as a key (a composite key). multifield composite keys can be expensive if the dataset gets very big. rather than using a multiple field composite key, its a better option to introduce a "surrogate key". This makes it easy for us to join the 2 tables using an intermediate table as well as acts well in terms of performance.